# Configure MySQL to Periodically Dump all Data

Tags: mysql

I would like to configure MySQL to periodically dump all data to a `.sql` file so that if something happens to my server and I need to start over, I can use the file to put all of the data back in place. How can I do this? I can take suggestions either involving use of the MySQL Workbench user interface to configure it or using a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into [mysqldump.exe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). This is probably the easiest way to dump the entire database into a raw SQL file.

Then you'll want to set up a script that calls mysqldump.exe with the appropriate parameters and set up a Windows Scheduled Task or Linux chron job to call the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) command. Assuming you want to make a backup of all databases now:

```
mysqldump -hMY_HOST.COM -uDB_USERNAME -pDB_PASSWORD USERNAME_DATABASENAME > MysqlDump.sql
```

To run periodic backups, you can setup a server cron which runs the mysqldump command after some interval (e.g. 24 hours)

```
mysqldump -hMY_HOST.COM -uDB_USERNAME -pDB_PASSWORD USERNAME_DATABASENAME > MysqlDump.sql
```

After creating the dump file. Setup another cron to copy this dump to the target server(say a local server) make this execute with same interval of above cron. You can use [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) (secure copy) for this:

```
scp user@MY_HOST.COM:/some/path/file user2@MY_HOST2.COM:/some/path/file
```

**NOTE:** The mysqldump command can cause high server load depending on the database size (make sure you are executing them when server having minimum load).

**Cron Job:**
To setup a cron job, you put the above backup command in a .sh file, then you create the cron by running:

```
sudo crontab -e    // Open your root crontab file
0 0 * * * USERNAME /path/to/script.sh  // Run a cronjob at midnight every day
```

More on cronjobs: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/